# how to send an alert message to other web page when any model field in changed

Tags: javascript, html, django, model, alert

I have an Offer model in my Django application:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    Auction_id=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name = "Auction ID",default=number)
    Offer_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name = "Auction Name")
    Auction_des=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name = "Auction Description")
    Bid_Start_Time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    Bid_End_Time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

and I have a Bid web page displaying details related to the offer.
I want to display an alert message to the Bid web page every time the Bid end time in the offer is changed.
Through the init and save method in the offer I can check whether Bid end time is modified or not but I'm not able to display the alert message on Bid web page.

Comment: You basically want to send a message from the server to the client, this can be done with socket.io for instance.

Comment: You can use post_save() signal for this. Whenever there is a modification in model, trigger a signal to send alert.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha can you please explain how can i send alert from model post save signal to bid template.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by using signal functionality.
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#:~:text=Django%20includes%20a%20%E2%80%9Csignal%20dispatcher,some%20action%20has%20taken%20place.&text=Sent%20when%20Django%20starts%20or%20finishes%20an%20HTTP%20request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#:%7E:text=Django%20includes%20a%20%E2%80%9Csignal%20dispatcher,some%20action%20has%20taken%20place.&text=Sent%20when%20Django%20starts%20or%20finishes%20an%20HTTP%20request).

Comment: I'm not able to understand how will i send alert messgae from model signal to bid template.Please help.